# Android:- How to Make dynamic HashMap Accessible in whole application?

Tags: android, hashmap

I have one problem is i am parsing data from google api which returns me 
`JSON` data.
  I stored that data in `HashMap<string,String>.` 
which is dynamic.
Now i want to make it accessible in my another classes of application.
so i am confuse how to make it accessible in other classes without making static.
is there any solution? if u have any sample code please send.
i tried using `static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`
but it dosen't make scence because responce is dynamic.
So i need dynamic hashmap which can be accessed in more than one class.

Thanks for help.
Mahaveer.
mahaveermuttha@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Android provide Application Context that you could subclass and use it in other activities. The steps are (I also highlight the links so you could read up on important things):

- Modify your [Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) to include the custom Application. Look at the following section in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.mypackage.application.MyCustomApplication">
....
```

The android:name="com.mypackage.application.MyCustomApplication" referring to the class MyCustomApplication which is the subclass of [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) that you are going to create

- Now, it's time for you to make your subclass. In here you want to make sure you include HashMap<string,String> as part of its variable. So your subclass would look like

```
    public class  MyCustomApplication extends Application {
        HashMap myMap;

        public MyCustomApplication() {
            this.myMap = new HashMap();
        }

        public HashMap getMyMap() {
            return myMap;
        }
    }
```

- Once you do that, now you can access your map from any Activity by calling [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29). Make sure you cast the Application to MyCustomApplication to use it properly and get access to the method getMyMap()

Let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: can we heavy functions in this class?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object and making the HashMap a field on that Application object. All your Services and Activities could then access it there.

Comment: Thanks For The Help Femi. I am New To Android and also on Java. Can You Please Illustrate By some Code... i am trying on it from last two days. n i am not getting the solution.. Thanks once again.