# Unable to extend Main Activity with CustomHashMap

Tags: android

Ref: [Android:- How to Make dynamic HashMap Accessible in whole application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200940/android-how-to-make-dynamic-hashmap-accessible-in-whole-application)
I have set up a CustomHashMap (just a collection of 3 LinkedHashMaps) so that I can access it from 2 Activities, but I am
unable to access it from the SecondActivity! The only way to remove red errors in Manifest.xml is to set the lines below. If I
use *android:name="com.example.intents.CustomHashMap"* (following the online example) I get an error saying *'is not an enclosing
class'.*

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
    android:name="com.example.intents.MainActivity$CustomHashMap">  //--- The system added the $ parts here.
    <activity
    ....
 protected CustomHashMap thisMap;
 ....
 thisMap = (MainActivity.CustomHashMap)getApplication();
```

In MainActivity I can do things like *thisMap.getKeyValue(4)* but from SecondActivity only null is returned. I feel as if I am
missing something very simple here. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just make this a static class containing these Hashmaps? Your error is telling you your class is nested inside the First Activity. post this activity please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As see here [android:name](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) :

*The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application*

Means need to pass class name which extends `Application` instead of any other component name like Activity,Service,...

See following tutorial for adding `Application` class in application :

[Global Variable Or Application Context Variable - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136)

Comment: All fixed. You are right as I had the CustomHashMap in the wrong class. I made a new Activity (CustomHashMap) and all works as it should.